# How to manipulate your Data Set based on the values of your index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have this Dataset, [wind_modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDO5.png). In this Dataset, columns are the locations and Index is the Date. And the Values in the columns are the wind speeds.
Let's say I want to find the average wind speed in January for each location, how do I use groupby or any other method to find the average?
Would it be possible without resetting the INDEX?
Edit - [This][2] is the actual dataset. I have combined the three columns "Yr, Mo, Dy" into one i.e. "DATE" and made it the INDEX.
I imported the dataset by using `pd.read_fwf`.
And "DATE" is of type datetime64[ns].

[2]:

Comment: you can use index.groupby().
Specifically for avg wind speeds in January just use index.dt.month.groupby(), if its datetime already and if not make, it datetime first.

Comment: Can you provide the sample dataframe in text format instead of image, so that others can copy paste and execute it ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example for your data.The index can be used for grouping, no worries.

Comment: I just uploaded the dataset file. You can check it out in the EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if want all Januaries for all years first filter them by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and add `mean`:

```
#if necessary convert index to DatetimeIndex
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df1 = df[df.index.month == 1].mean().to_frame().T
```

Or if need each January for each year separately after filter use `groupby` with [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and aggregate `mean`:

```
df2 = df[df.index.month == 1]
df3 = df2.groupby(df2.index.year).mean()
```